# Can we add a tag for Workflow 2013

Tags: feature-request, tags, version-tags

Is there a need in the tags to differentiate between SharePoint workflow and the new in 2013 workflow manager that is not specifically for SharePoint? There are a few new and big features in workflow manager with SP 2013 that will make those answers occasionally irrelevant for users of a previous versions.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a tag for [workflow-manager](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/workflow-manager), so I guess that answers your question. But if you'd like you could improve the tag wiki so we know what its for. The only link I find valuable is [Installing and Configuring Workflow Manager 1.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193478.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I feel as though Workflow Manager is specific to the installation/setup and not pertaining with the implementation and integration with SharePoint 2013. I agree here with @ghangas, at least a tag synonym for workflow 2013 would be a good idea. Plus workflow manager is a little ambiguous for those users that aren't sure what workflow manager pertains to.